# How to determine why certain settings from .editorconfig are not applied?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, editorconfig

I am tweaking naming guidelines in my project and am running into trouble with certain rules. I've installed Resharper to see which settings are applied and which are not. For example:

[image: editorconfig settings not applied]

As you can see `charset` for some reason is not applied. Same for `dotnet_naming_style` settings - I would love to know why that is. I obviously don't have any other overriding `.editorconfig` files so especially for `charset` it's confusing why that setting is not active.

What's the best way of debugging and resolving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are not yet supported by ReSharper, that's why they are striked through. They still could be used by Visual Studio and other tools, just not by ReSharper. I guess we should highlight unsupported, but syntactically correct properties in other way. I filed an issue for that (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-470700).
We plan to support naming settings in later releases, but we don't have plans to support charset setting, that should be better done by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry posted the part why ReSharper displays data with strike-through. But the debugging part was equally important for me and I managed to figure that one out.

Mads Kristensen has (of course) created extension that highlights errors within .editorconfig file and also provides few utility methods. It's on Visual Studio Marketplace:

[EditorConfig Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.EditorConfig)

Also looking through the list of recent questions another good extension that will be addressing this problem is [Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSIntelliCode). I've found it by looking at this question: [Export Visual Studio's 'Code Style settings' as .editorconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356453/export-visual-studios-code-style-settings-as-editorconfig?rq=1)